# What is a 'hidden gem'?

Tags: support

The guidance notes for ELU's 'late answers' review queue state,

> This is a new user's answer to an old question. Watch for **hidden gems**, non-answers, and spam.

A search for this term on the meta site returns no results. Nor could I see anything that looked relevant in a similar search on Google.

Can someone tell me what a hidden gem is in this context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "hidden gem" is a good thing hidden amoung not good things.

Given that a lot of new users need help adjusting to SE, it's fair to assume their first posts won't shine like a diamond. But it's possible one will. Look out for those.

Comment: Thanks. I was evidently misled by the proximity of "non-answers and spam" into assuming it was a reference to some sort of spurious contribution.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean. Like "Watch for hidden gems, i.e. non-answers and spam"?

Comment: Yes, more or less. I was inferring that because spam and non-answers were mentioned in the same breath (so to speak), 'hidden gems' might refer to some kind of trolling technique or other anti-social online activities.